# Excel: copy results of pull down menu

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook to complete numerous forms. One sheet contains numerous data elements (names, emails, etc.) for each cell. I have one generic data entry spreadsheet that has several pull down menus (data validation lists) contained in the data elements tab.

I'd like to copy the results of the pull down to another spreadsheet within the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Worksheet_Change event, let suppose pull down menu in cell E1 of Sheet1, put this code into Sheet1 module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$1" Then Sheets(2).Range("A1") = Target.Value
End Sub
```